# Get oldest customers with API

Tags: customer, api, magento-1, api-filter

I'm trying to get list of ~40k customers through Magento SOAP Api v2, with `customerCustomerList` method. I don't have access to Magento instance, only WSDL and credentials.

When I'm calling for **all** customers, i'm getting either `null` or `SoapFault` exception due to "*too many customers*" being fetched (no error is specified, but I research them - that's the reason).

I'm trying to split the call with `created_on` range and fetching customers per day, starting from now and going backwards, the problem is - how do I know I should stop?

Do you know a way I can fetch any timestamp 100% sure that there won't be any customers before it, like "oldest customer", or anything similar?

Comment: Could you add the code of the actual API call you are doming now to get the contacts with `created_on` filter?

Comment: the code is almost exactly the same as in http://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/XML-RPC-orders-list-how-to-filter-by-date-or-date-range/td-p/1405

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch the customers by `created_on` date day by day as you already do. Then when you have encountered like 7 days with no customers created, then you should change the API filter for `created_on` to a wider range, for instance a full month.

If you don't have new customers for three months, you could change the range to one year, or even wider. Until you reach a point where you think it is safe to do a call with a filter like "created_on < YYYY-mm-dd", where the date would be the last date you have searched on.

Comment: Yes, that's some way to work this around, but resulting in even more API calls and more border conditions to take into account (what if there wil be 2 years of no customers, and then 100k in one week?). What would be the best is **any** timestamp that I can get through API